# Differentiate between an unset value and 0 in an mapping

Tags: solidity, mapping

How can I know if a key is unset?

The [Solidity documenation on Mappings](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings) says:

> Mappings can be seen as hash tables which are virtually initialized such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros: a type’s default value.

If I'm mapping to an int, how can I differentiate between key with a value which is set to zero, vs key with an unset value which defaults to 0x0?

Comment: If zero has meaning, then you have to explicitly set a flag. Have a look at Mapping with Struct over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity/13168#13168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to do this, I would use two mappings, one for the values and one to check whether if the address is used (keeping a flag -  as @RobHitchens has suggested in a comment).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Example {

    mapping(address => uint) public values;
    mapping(address => bool) public usedAddresses;


    function update(uint newVal) {

        values[msg.sender] = newVal;
        usedAddresses[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function dosomethiingwithval(){

        if(usedAddresses[msg.sender]){ 

             //do whatever with values[msg.sender]
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't `if(values[msg.sender] || usedAddresses[msg.sender])` save gas?

Comment: yeah great of course :)

Comment: I'll update the answer :)

Comment: The order should actually be `if ( usedAddresses[msg.sender]||values[msg.sender] )`  ;)